# Help track and improve traffic

Tags: discussion

Here's what I'm asking everyone to do

When you link a question on an external site (faceook, g+, forums, etc.) post an answer here with which question you linked and which site.

The purpose is so that we can look at correlation between traffic and sharing to see if some questions are particularly good for sharing and encourage other users to share them (appropriately of course, no spam!).